# Мне не интересно / неинтересно твоё предложение

Tags: орфография

Как правильно?

> Мне не интересно / неинтересно твоё предложение.

Answer (score 1):

**Выбор варианта** (утверждение или отрицание) зависит от ситуации, например:

Вариант 1. **Обоснование после**  основного высказывания (**логическое подчеркивание** отрицания):

*Мне **не интерЕсно** /твоё предложение. Я уже много раз слышал подобное.*

Вариант 2. **Обоснование до** основного высказывания (нет логического выделения):

*Я уже много раз слышал подобное. Поэтому мне **неинтересно** твоё предложЕние.*

https://quasa.io/ru/media/vozrazhenie-mne-eto-ne-interesno

**НЕИНТЕРЕСНО**, нареч. 1. к Неинтересный (1 зн.). Н. рассказывать. Н. читать лекции. 2. в функц. сказ. Об отсутствии интереса у кого-л. к чему-л. Мне н. здесь. Совсем н., как она будет одета.

**ИНТЕРЕСНО**
интересно, нареч. и в знач. сказ.
О наличии интереса к кому-чему-л., заинтересованности в ком-чём-л.,